# Construtor Autowiring calling three times (Spring 5)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am working with spring 5, I have written a class CacheManger which I use to cache data manually, I have autowired the constructor with help of annotation. I have injected this object in other spring beans. The problem is that when I start the tomcat, this constructor is being called three times. I don't know why? Please help me out.

This is a legacy system built in struts , need to upgrade this, pls see also web.xml contents, why context is being created for ActionServlet

This is my class:-

```
@Component
public class CacheManager {

    UtilDAO utilDao;

    @Autowired
    public CacheManager(UtilDAO utilDAO) {
        System.out.println("Calling the CacheManager Constructor...");
        this.utilDao = utilDAO;
        loadValueMaps();
    }

    private HashMap mapOfValueMaps = null;


    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.SUPPORTS)
    public void loadValueMaps(int branchId) {
        List tmpLst = this.utilDao.getValueMapsList(branchId);

        if (this.mapOfDealerLang == null) {
            this.mapOfDealerLang = new HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<ALang>>();
        }

        ArrayList<AValue> list = this.mapOfValueMaps.get(branchId);
        if (list == null) {
            list = new ArrayList<ALang>(1);
            this.mapOfDealerLang.put(branchId, list);
        } else
            list.clear();

        for (Iterator iter = tmpLst.iterator(); iter.hasNext();) {
            AValue element = (AValue) iter.next();
            list.add(element);
        }
    }
```

This is my Dao Layer

```
@Repository
public class UtilDAOImpl extends DatabaseConnection implements UtilDAO {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("sessionFactoryBean")
    SessionFactory sessionfactoryBean;

    @Autowired
    public void setSessionFactoryBean() {
        setSessionFactory(sessionfactoryBean);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.SUPPORTS)
    public List getValueMapsList() {
        String query = "from AValue as blk  where blk.blkActive = :blval";
        List reqList = findbyParam(query, "blval", true);
        Set setItems = new LinkedHashSet(reqList);
        reqList.clear();
        reqList.addAll(setItems);
        return reqList;
    }
}
```

This is DI for this:-

```
@Component
public class ListActionManager {


    @Autowired
    ViewService vwService;

    @Autowired
    CacheManager cachMang;


    public void getList(int pageNo,DisplayListForm form, SessionBean bean) throws Exception{
        try{
            ListView lstVw=null;
            int maxResult=25;
            int totalRecords=0;

            lstVw = vwService.getList(bean.getBranch_ind(),ssUsrBn.getBranch_main_ind(),pageNo,maxResult,totalRecords);}
            form.setdata(lstVw);
        }catch(Exception ex){
            throw ex;
        }
    }
}
```

Console log after starting tomcat:-

```
Apr 25, 2020 11:55:29 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://struts.apache.org/tags-html is already defined
Apr 25, 2020 11:55:29 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://struts.apache.org/tags-logic is already defined
Apr 25, 2020 11:55:29 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://struts.apache.org/tags-nested is already defined
Apr 25, 2020 11:55:29 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig execute
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Apr 25, 2020 11:55:29 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
Apr 25, 2020 11:55:29 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.


**Calling the CacheManager Constructor...**


Apr 25, 2020 11:55:35 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'actionbean'


**Calling the CacheManager Constructor...**


Apr 25, 2020 11:55:37 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing WebApplicationContext for Struts ActionServlet 'servlet', module ''

**Calling the CacheManager Constructor...**


Apr 25, 2020 11:55:39 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Apr 25, 2020 11:55:39 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Apr 25, 2020 11:55:39 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 12491 ms
```

This web.xml

```
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>



  <servlet>
        <servlet-name>servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
          <param-name>config</param-name>
          <param-value>/WEB-INF/struts-config.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>       
        <init-param>
            <param-name>debug</param-name>
            <param-value>2</param-value>
        </init-param>       
        <init-param>
            <param-name>detail</param-name>
            <param-value>2</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>  

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: please help about this

Comment: Because you are loading everything 3 times. Don't.

Comment: @M.Deinum, I got ur point, I have omiited for DispatcherSevelt but ActionServlet I cannt

Comment: Split your configuration properly. Your `ContextLoaderListener` should load the generic things like datasources, services etc. The action-servlet one should only load the struts related things (or nothing and only delegate to the root context (the context-loader-listener one). That way you only load things once.

Answer (score 1):

The bean is creating for each `ApplicationContext`. You have three `ApplicationContext`

```
Spring root WebApplicationContext
Spring DispatcherServlet ApplicationContext
WebApplicationContext for Struts ActionServlet
```

Comment: Spring DispatcherServlet ApplicationContext, I have used this expose system for API

Comment: how can I avoid this WebApplicationContext for Struts ActionServlet